# Flatiron Union "after" functions execute before "before" functions?

Tags: flatiron.js

I am working on a Flatiron Union-based app, and it seems that the simple logger I am developing logs before the routes are run, so it does not accurately report what happened. I took the logger sample code from the Union examples. Here's a stripped down code sample:

```
 var
   union = require('union')
   , server;

 server = union.createServer({
   before: [ function (req,res) {
     console.log('before');
     res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
     res.end("Hello World");
   } ],
   after: [
     function LoggerStream() {
         var stream   = new union.ResponseStream();
         stream.once("pipe", function (req) {
           console.log({res: this.res.statusCode, method: this.req.method});
         });
         return stream;
     }
   ]
 });

 server.listen(8800);
 console.log('union running on 8800');
```

Here's what appears in my console:

```
 $ DEBUG=*  node ./union.js
 union running on 8800
 { res: 200, method: 'GET' }
 before
```

Note that the reported status is 200 when the http server actually returned a 404.

Why is this running out of order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recent reply to your question from our mailing list by [indexzero](http://twitter.com/indexzero):

> Stuart,
>
> This is actually expected behavior. A pipe chain is constructed by a
>   union.RoutingStream instance from:
>
> union.ResponseStream() --> after0 --> after1 --> after2 --> ... -->
>   aftern --> http.Response() (see
>   https://github.com/flatiron/union/blob/master/lib/routing-stream.js#L74-83)
>
> So the `pipe` event on every Stream in the after chain is invoked
>   immediately, but everyone of those Streams has an opportunity to
>   modify the data sent to the response by implementing their own .pipe()
>   method.
>
> So for example if your LoggingStream was
>
> var stream   = new union.ResponseStream(); stream.once("data",
>   function (req) {   console.log({res: this.res.statusCode, method:
>   this.req.method}); }); return stream;
>
> You would see the console.log statements fire in the order you expect.
>   It might be useful to read Max Ogden's recent blog post on Streams in
>   node.js and how they work: http://maxogden.com/node-streams
>
> Cheers, Charlie

If you have more questions, you can find us on github, irc (#nodejitsu on freenode) and our mailing list at flatironjs@googlegroups.com . :)

Comment: See the conversation: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/flatironjs/9EFr2YWx8xY